# Quickest way to get StatusCode while posting data

Tags: c#

What i'm wanting to do it post data (`ID=123456&start=true`) and have it return the website status (200, 404, 401, etc.)
I don't want any other content except for the `StatusCode`, what is my best way of doing this?

I have been using

```
HttpWebRequest request =
    (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://example.com/test.php");
request.Method = "POST";
```

But it seems to download the whole page before it gives me the `StatusCode`.

I have also tried:

```
request.Method = "HEAD";
```

But that wont let me send any post data with it.

Comment: what about this... `HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
(int)response.StatusCode` ....????

Comment: since you have put an '?' in the beginning of data, are you sure that it needs to be POSTed? Isn't it just part of the URL? Something like example.com/?ID=123456&start=true ?

Comment: @Mehrzad Chehraz Sorry that was a mistake, please ignore that (i have fixed up the post)